# How to make Spring Boot include the manifest file in its repackaged WAR?

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, war, manifest

I'm building a Spring Boot application using `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `2.1.0-RELEASE` and need it to produce a deployable WAR file containing a `MANIFEST.MF` in the `META-INF/` directory. I've set up the Maven WAR plugin to include the manifest in the build artifact:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
      </manifest>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However, the final build artifact doesn't include a manifest file. I noticed that Spring Boot performs a repackaging after the Maven WAR plugin packaged the WAR file in the first place:

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.0.RELEASE:repackage (repackage)
```

And indeed the artifact.war.original in the `target` directory does contain the manifest.

How do I make Spring Boot to include the manifest in the final WAR file as well?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that in "repacked" WAR (at least not in the place you want it to be) as it contains custom loading mechanisms. Repacked WAR is still 'deployable'

Comment: I need the manifest file in the deployed WAR to obtain the application version at runtime.

Comment: Dont do this via manifest, do this via application properties. This can be interpolated during build.

Comment: So its XY Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` for this as below.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

<build>
    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.yourMainClass</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```